# How can you shorten ||?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
if (5 > 2 || 6 > 2 || 7 > 2) {
    console.log("Two is small");
} else {
    console.log("Two is big");
}
```

Is there a way to shorten it? I am looking for something like this (the code below doesn't work):

```
if (5, 6, 7 > 2) {
    console.log("Two is small");
else {
    console.log("Two is big");
}
```

Comment: Well, the question here is about shortening multiple ||'s, the expressions being ||'d don't necessarily have to be value comparisons

Comment: The linked question is about comparing with equality. This one--at least in the sample code--is not just equality, which changes the options other than "just list them all out".

Comment: OP, if you want to check if a list of values are all greater than some other value, you can use `Math.min`, e.g. `if (Math.min(5, 6, 7) > 2) {//do stuff}`